# Publish/Subscribe Pattern in C# WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe

How to register client on server to listen some change? I want to notify my client and send some data when something changed on my server. Also, I use NetTcpBinding. I tried many examples, but I can't get method from server to register in. I don't have any config file.

Thanks in advance.

There is example of registering client on server.

```
ChannelFactory<ITrending> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITrending>(
            new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"net.tcp://localhost:6000/ITrending"));

        proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Start by reading this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service come back with follow up questions and example code you have created and issues you have.

Comment: @Janne Matikainen It's fine explanation. I've already tried this. But, there's no example for Client and I don't have configuration file.

Comment: In the article there is a section called "Creating the client application"

Comment: What is the problem you have? That you can't connect to the server? As far as I know NetTcpBinding requires TransportEncryption at least in order to connect.

Comment: @myst3rium I can connect to the server and get data, but I can't get method and register my client to server for notifications. This example of registering client for server worked, I can't notify client when some event happens in server. My problem is register client on server for notification.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Yeah, I see... But, there is configuration file which I don't have. I can't follow complete tutorial. I've already implemented some functionality, but I have to add publish/subscribe or observer pattern.

Comment: Having a configuration is not a prerequisite, main points from the tutorial is having a duplex channel to the server with a callback and registering the clients callbacks to the server for notifying the clients later on. You need to use DuplexChannelFactory to create the channel to the server. Your example code is not really registering the client to the server, it is just creating a channel to a non duplex mode wcf service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CallBack functionality in WCF services , it can be used for sending the changes in any entity or object value. In this case, Client must act as a server and server as a Client to receive the updates based on the method in the Client which is receiving the changes. 
More detailed explanation : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/721/push-data-wcf-callback-service

Comment: There is config file again. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: There is only the binding which is different from your in config , do you want to change the binding optionally ?